# Fetching tax information for customers in contact and if not tax present creating tax in zoho using API

Tags: python, zoho

I am integrating my software with zoho book to create invoice but now am stuck to connect the customers of my contacts with the taxes that are key details needed to generate an invoice, I want for each customer in my contact to access the information of tax using API, and if not yet created the tax we should create new one for that customer using API, I will provide some code for `get_tax()` method:

```
def get_tax(self, tax):
        try:
            response = requests.get(
                    f"https://www.zohoapis.com/books/v3/settings/taxes?organization_id={self.organization_id}",
                    headers=self.get_header(),
                )
            
            # re-authenticate
            if response.status_code == 401:
                self.__access_token
                return self.get_tax()

            else:
                tax_id = ""
                response_data = response.json()
                # checking for the customer
                if "taxes" in response_data:
                    for tax in response_data["taxes"]:
                        # if customer exists
                        if tax.get("customer_name","").lower() == tax_name.lower():
                            # update customer_id
                            customer_id = tax.get("contact_id","")
                            print("Customer found:", tax_id)
                            break
                
                if not tax_id:
                    try:
                        data = {
                            "tax_name": "Sales Group",
                            "tax_percentage": 10.5,
                            "tax_type": "tax",
                            "tax_factor": "rate",
                            "tax_authority_name": "Illinois Department of Revenue",
                            "country_code": "UK",
                        }
                        response = requests.post(
                            f"https://www.zohoapis.com/books/v3/settings/taxes?organization_id={self.organization_id}",
                            headers=self.get_header(),
                            json=data,
                        )
                        
                        response_data = response.json()
                        
                        # Check if the API response contains the necessary data
                        if "tax" in response_data and "tax_id" in response_data["tax"]:
                            tax_id = response_data["tax"]["tax_id"]
                            print("New tax created:", tax_id)
                        else:
                            print("Failed to create new tax.")
                            tax_id = None
                    except Exception as e:
                            print("Error occurred when creating a new tax:", e)
                            traceback.print_exc()
                            tax_id = None
                return tax_id
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error occurred:", e)
            traceback.print_exc()
            return None
```

I tried already to create the method to get tax if present and if no tax present it should create new one.

Comment: it does not make sense to put all the code into a `try` block... if you want to try certain code lines then do that.